# I cannot download pdf output for beamer presentation in Rstudio

Tags: r, download, output, r-markdown, beamer

I am using Rmarkdown to prepare a beamer presentation. When I compile the output via knitr, I can see the final compilation of the pdf document in ViewPDF. However, when I try to download it by clicking on the download button in the upper right hand corner, it does not function--I click and click, but nothing happens. Do I need to download/upgrade my current versions? I am using R 3.3.2 and have Rstudio v. 1.0.136. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean download? If you are using Rstudio on your local machine, the pdf will be saved in the same directory as your .Rmd file.

Comment: Ok, yes, that works. Thanks!

Comment: would be nice if there was some feedback. I was clicking and looked liked nothing was happening